Unable to verify if logback is the sole logging implementation with jqassistant
I am trying to verify with jqassistant that we only implement logback (and slf4j) for logging.
I'm using version: 2.4.0 and the analyze goal seems to be successful but it shouldn't be. For testing purpose I added a dependency to log4j2.
The following resources are needed to reproduce the problem.
Parent pom.xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <revision>8.0.2-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>

    <springdoc-openapi.version>2.2.0</springdoc-openapi.version>
    <spring-cloud-dependencies.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud-dependencies.version>
    <spring-cloud-starter-stream-solace.version>4.0.0</spring-cloud-starter-stream-solace.version>
    <azure-identity.version>1.10.1</azure-identity.version>
    <microsoft-graph.version>5.70.0</microsoft-graph.version>
    <org-json.version>20230227</org-json.version>
    <commons-validatior.version>1.7</commons-validatior.version>
    <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.8</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>

    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>../target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
    </sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
    <flatten-maven-plugin.version>1.6.0</flatten-maven-plugin.version>
    <fmt-maven-plugin.version>2.19</fmt-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-scm-plugin.version>2.0.1</maven-scm-plugin.version>
    <jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin.version>1.2.1</jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin.version>

    <!-- jqassistant -->
    <jqassistant-maven-plugin.version>2.4.0</jqassistant-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>myapp-backend</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-dependencies.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jqassistant</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jqassistant-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>scan</goal>
                                <goal>analyze</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${flatten-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
                <flattenMode>resolveCiFriendliesOnly</flattenMode>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>flatten</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten.clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify.fmt</groupId>
            <artifactId>fmt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${fmt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <style>google</style>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>format-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
            <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jqassistant-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

myapp-backend/pom.xml looks like this (notice that I added a dependency to spring-boot-starter-log4j2)
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>myapp-backend</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.solace.spring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-solace</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-starter-stream-solace.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-binder</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>${org-json.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
        <version>${azure-identity.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
                <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
        <version>${microsoft-graph.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc-openapi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-validatior.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
        <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-info</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

In the root folder I have the .jqassistant.yml
jqassistant:
  scan:
    reset: false
  analyze:
    report:
      warn-on-severity: MINOR
      fail-on-severity: MAJOR
      properties:
        junit.report.failureSeverity: MAJOR
        junit.report.errorSeverity: MINOR
  maven:
    use-execution-root-as-project-root: true

.mvn/jvm.config
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED

jqassistant/rules.xml
All of the following rules should fail due to the fact that I have a log4j2 dependency and not a logback one
<jqa:jqassistant-rules xmlns:jqa="http://www.buschmais.com/jqassistant/core/rule/schema/v1.3">

<constraint id="logging:use-logback">
    <description>Ensures that Logback is used for logging.</description>
    <cypher><![CDATA[
          MATCH
            (app:Application)-[:CONTAINS]->(type:Type)
          WHERE NOT (
            (type)-[:DECLARES]->()-[:OF_TYPE]->(:Type {fqn:"ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger"})
            OR
            (type)-[:DECLARES]->()-[:INVOKES]->()<-[:DECLARES]-(:Type {fqn:"org.slf4j.LoggerFactory"})
          )
          RETURN type.fqn AS InvalidType
        ]]>
    </cypher>
</constraint>

<constraint id="logging:only-logback">
    <description>Ensure only Logback is used as the logging framework.</description>
    <cypher><![CDATA[
    MATCH (dep:Dependency)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(artifact:Artifact)
    WHERE artifact.groupId IN ['org.slf4j', 'log4j', 'commons-logging', 'java.util.logging']
      AND NOT (artifact.groupId = 'org.slf4j' AND artifact.artifactId IN ['slf4j-api', 'jul-to-slf4j'])
      AND artifact.artifactId <> 'logback-classic'
    RETURN dep.fqn AS InvalidDependency, artifact.groupId AS GroupId, artifact.artifactId AS ArtifactId
    ]]></cypher>
</constraint>

<constraint id="logging:deny-spring-boot-starter-log4j2">
    <description>Deny usage of spring-boot-starter-log4j2</description>
    <cypher><![CDATA[
    MATCH (dep:Dependency)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(artifact:Artifact)
    WHERE artifact.groupId = 'org.springframework.boot'
    AND artifact.artifactId = 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    AND artifact.version = '3.1.3'
    RETURN dep.fqn AS InvalidDependency, artifact.groupId AS GroupId, artifact.artifactId AS ArtifactId, artifact.version AS Version
]]></cypher>
</constraint>


<group id="default">
    <includeConstraint refId="logging:use-logback"/>
    <includeConstraint refId="logging:only-logback"/>
    <includeConstraint refId="logging:deny-spring-boot-starter-log4j2"/>
</group>

Could the error be related to these warnings that I receive?

[WARNING] Neo.ClientNotification.Statement.UnknownRelationshipTypeWarning - The
provided relationship type is not in the database.: One of the r
elationship types in your query is not available in the database, make
sure you didn't misspell it or that the label is available when you
run this statement in your application (the missing relationship type
is: OF_TYPE) (at 5:42)

...

[WARNING] Neo.ClientNotification.Statement.UnknownLabelWarning - The
provided label is not in the database.: One of the labels in your
query is  not available in the database, make sure you didn't misspell
it or that the label is available when you run this statement in your
application (the missing label name is: Application) (at 3:36)

...

[WARNING] Neo.ClientNotification.Statement.UnknownPropertyKeyWarning -
The provided property key is not in the database: One of the property
nam es in your query is not available in the database, make sure you
didn't misspell it or that the label is available when you run this
statement in your application (the missing property name is: groupId)
(at 6:55)

How can I use jqassistant to verify that logback is the only logging implementation that is being used? Why are these rules not working and how can I modify them?
